# How to load satellite assemblies relative to DLL

Tags: c#, .net, satellite-assembly, language-translation

I have a situation where I supply a plugin DLL that uses .NET 4.0. This DLL uses ResourceManager to load strings. The strings in turn get translated and compiled into satellite assemblies.

I'm not the author of the main EXE that loads and uses my plugin DLL. It's running from another directory. Because of this, the DLL cannot find its satellite assemblies. ResourceManager wants to find them under the EXE directory rather than the directory in which the DLL sits.

**How can I get the ResourceManager to load satellite assemblies relative to the DLL?**

Answer (score 0):

If the main exe reads settings from a configuration file that you're allowed to change you could use the `<codeBase>` tag there as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908).

Comment: Nice idea, but doesn't fit my situation. The EXE is Explorer, and the DLL we control is a context menu shell extension. I didn't mention that before because I didn't want to deal with the crap from everyone about writing a shell extension using .NET. It wasn't my code nor my design, I've just been given the job of making it work. :-(